# Microsoft.SharePoint.intl.resources missing

Tags: .net, sharepoint, wspbuilder, wsp, .net-3.5

I'm trying to use SPVisualDev to build and deploy my SharePoint feature.
It builds the WSP but it won't deploy it, failing with the following message:

> Failed to deploy solution 'MyProject.wsp'. **Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.intl.resources, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies.** The system cannot find the file specified.

It's true that there is no such assembly in GAC. I guess it has to be some satellite assembly but I just don't have it and I've no idea how to work around the issue.

This is the stack trace, as SPVisualDev provides it:

> System.Exception    at SPVisualDev.VSAddin.Connect.DeployWSP(IMainService mainService, String WSP_FilePath, Boolean GAC, String[] WebApplicationURLs)
>      at SPVisualDev.VSAddin.Connect.ExecuteWSPBuildAndDeploy(Boolean deploy)
>      at SPVisualDev.VSAddin.Connect.Exec(String commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, Object& varIn, Object& varOut, Boolean& handled)

Comment: Marek, thanks for your questions. Yes, `Microsoft.SharePoint` is in the GAC, as well as `Microsoft.SharePoint.intl`. I installed English version of SharePoint. No, I didn't install any language packs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I didn't manage to do that so I ended up writing my own `bat` file to do the deployment.